# Asynchronous javascript in a synchronous function when combining mediaStreams from getUserMedia and getDisplayMedia?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webrtc

My team is adapting the sipml5 library to create a html5 softphone for use in our organization.  The full repository is here: https://github.com/L1kMakes/sipml5-ng .  We have the code working well; audio and video calls work flawlessly.  In the original code we forked from (which was from like 2012) screen sharing was accomplished with a browser plugin, but HTML 5 and WebRTC have changed to allow this to be done with just JavaScript now.

I am having difficulty adapting the code to accommodate this.  I am starting with the code here on line 828: https://github.com/L1kMakes/sipml5-ng/blob/master/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_session_jsep.js This works, though without audio.  That makes sense as the only possible audio stream from a screen share is the screen audio, not the mic audio.  I am attempting to initialize an audio stream from getUserMedia, grab a video stream from getDisplayMedia, and present that to the client as a single mediaStream.  Here's my adapted code:

```
if ( this.e_type == tmedia_type_e.SCREEN_SHARE ) {
    // Plugin-less screen share using WebRTC requires "getDisplayMedia" instead of "getUserMedia"
    //  Because of this, audio constraints become limited, and we have to use async to deal with
    //  the promise variable for the mediastream.  This is a change since Chrome 71.  We are able
    //  to use the .then aspect of the promise to call a second mediaStream, then attach the audio
    //  from that to the video of our second screenshare mediaStream, enabling plugin-less screen
    //  sharing with audio.
    let o_stream = null;
    let o_streamAudio = null;
    let o_streamVideo = null;
    let o_streamAudioTrack = null;
    let o_streamVideoTrack = null;
    try {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
            {
                audio: false,
                video: !!( this.e_type.i_id & tmedia_type_e.VIDEO.i_id ) ? o_video_constraints : false
            }
        ).then(o_streamVideo => {
            o_streamVideoTrack = o_streamVideo.getVideoTracks()[0];
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                {
                    audio: o_audio_constraints,
                    video: false
                }
            ).then(o_streamAudio => {
                o_streamAudioTrack = o_streamAudio.getAudioTracks()[0];
                o_stream = new MediaStream( [ o_streamVideoTrack , o_streamAudioTrack ] );
                tmedia_session_jsep01.onGetUserMediaSuccess(o_stream, This);
            });
        });
    } catch ( s_error ) {
        tmedia_session_jsep01.onGetUserMediaError(s_error, This);
    }
} else {
    try {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            {
                audio: (this.e_type == tmedia_type_e.SCREEN_SHARE) ? false : !!(this.e_type.i_id & tmedia_type_e.AUDIO.i_id) ? o_audio_constraints : false,
                video: !!(this.e_type.i_id & tmedia_type_e.VIDEO.i_id) ? o_video_constraints : false // "SCREEN_SHARE" contains "VIDEO" flag -> (VIDEO & SCREEN_SHARE) = VIDEO
            }
        ).then(o_stream => {
            tmedia_session_jsep01.onGetUserMediaSuccess(o_stream, This);
        });
    } catch (s_error ) {
        tmedia_session_jsep01.onGetUserMediaError(s_error, This);
    }
}
```

My understanding is, o_stream should represent the resolved mediaStream tracks, not a promise, when doing a screen share.  On the other end, we are using the client "MicroSIP."  When making a video call, when the call is placed, I get my video preview locally in our web app, then when the call is answered the MicroSIP client gets a green square for a second, then resolves to my video.  When I make a screen share call, my local web app sees the local preview of the screen share, but upon answering the call, my MicroSIP client just gets a green square and never gets the actual screen share.

The video constraints for both are the same.  If I add debugging output to get more descriptive of what is actually in the media streams, they appear identical as far as I can tell.  I made a test video call and a test screen share call, captured debug logs from each and held them side by side in notepad++...all appears to be identical save for the explicit debug describing the traversal down the permission request tree with "GetUserMedia" and "GetDisplayMedia."  I can't really post the debug logs here as cleaning them up of information from my organization would leave them pretty barren.  Save for the extra debug output on the "getDisplayMedia" call before "getUserMedia", timestamps, and uniqueID's related to individual calls, the log files are identical.

I am wondering if the media streams are not resolving from their promises before the "then" is completed, but asynchronous javascript and promises is still a bit over my head.  I do not believe I should convert this function to async, but I have nothing else to debug here; the mediaStream is working as I can see it locally, but I'm stumped on figuring out what is going on with the remote send.

Comment: If the mediaStream is working locally then you are showing us the wrong code. Are you using RTCPeerConnection? Have you tried in another browser?

Comment: What do you mean?  That is a copy/paste from our live development branch and I just tested it, what is a signal that it isn't working?  I've tested in chrome since that's our org's standard.

Comment: The code you're showing seems fine but is not responsible for "remote send". Trying it in another browser might rule out browser bugs, to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was...nothing, the code was fine.  It turns out the recipient SIP client we were using had an issue where it just aborts if it gets video larger than 640x480.